# How do I open a file in a kernel module if calling process is in user space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to create a character device driver that dumps /etc/shadow when read from as a non-privileged user. This is for purely academic purposes of course.

I was reading about how reading/writing files in kernel space opens a system to possible exploits. I am trying to implement this in practice.

Please spare me the "don't touch the filesystem in kernel mode" talk. I am precisely trying to exploit the nuances of doing so.

Problem is that the only way I have found so far that works to open a file in kernel mode is `filp_open`, which is currently producing EACCESS when I read from the device file as a non-privileged user. This was confounding at first as I assumed that I can do anything in kernel space.

For example, when I cat the device file I have created as a non-root user, filp_open produces EACCESS in kernel space???

Further investigation has led me to believe that filp_open checks the capabilities of the calling process. This would make sense as it is used internally by open(), but I am in kernel mode here! There must be a way!

I am very new to programming in kernel space. I have extensive application C experience, but I am finding it difficult to navigate the kernel documentation for precisely what I am looking for. Additionally, it seems that more and more symbols within the kernel are not exported for use in modules. As I am developing an exploit proof of concept, I would like it to work without recompiling the kernel. I am finding a lot of code (vfs and syscalls) that is deprecated as the symbols are no longer exported to kernel modules.

Is what I am trying to do a thing that is specifically engineered against? Loading a kernel module requires root to begin with, so I would see this more in the lens of a persistence focused attack rather than an access one.

Also, I got the proof of concept working by just reading from the file when the module is loaded, but this is no fun! Any pointers here are much appreciated.

Comment: While the hacking in educational purposes is not bad, do not expect Linux kernel is welcomed for such hacking. Of course, as you are in the kernel space, no one can prevent you from doing anything. But doing bad things could be hard. This is not because Linux kernel developers dislike hackers. This is because they like when "normal" developers write a **correct code**. "I was reading about how reading/writing files in kernel space opens a system to possible exploits." - This is probably a reason why they do not provide API for write kernel code which could be subject for exploits.

Comment: As for your specific problem - opening a file with "secure" permissions from user process - it seems you need to manually elevate permissions before calling `filp_open`. Or create in-kernel thread which would open the file. Or create a "work" which could be executed via workqueue mechanism ("works" are executed in the context of pre-created in-kernel threads).

Comment: Kernel modules must be loaded by root.  Open /etc/shadow in the init routine.

Comment: Ah I never thought about opening the file in init and then just keeping it open. That’s genius but also not entirely what I was going for. Expansion on this is to open any file that his written to the module and then read it out on read. But this achieves what I need for now! Thanks! Also thank you for the explanation Tsyvarev! I think that is the direction I need to go to get this really working well.

Answer (score 0):

After some rethinking and digging I have found two solutions to my problem. Thank you to Tsyvarev and stark for the pointers.

**Solution 1**

The first solution is to elevate the privileges of the calling process before making a call of `filp_open`. This is also basically making a rootkit, so not as interesting.

Here is a link to the guide that I found on the subject.
https://0x00sec.org/t/kernel-rootkits-getting-your-hands-dirty/1485

**Solution 2**

The module will have an init function that by nature must be run with elevated privs when the module is loaded. So you can open the file pointer there and just close it when the module is unloaded. Caveats are that you have the file pointer open the whole time, so all of the gotchas there are still present. Better to only read, writing is where things can get a bit tricky. This is the solution I chose in the interim, as I didn't want this thing to be a full rootkit.

Another direction is workqueue or to spawn a thread. Probably the most tricky but also the most inline with what my original vision of this demo was. I did not test this direction but it probably is the best solution.